# How to get the page URL in Javascript and call script?

Tags: javascript, html

So basically, I want to only call some script if the URL does not equal `blogs.html`

For example, these parameters should NOT call the script:

```
mydomains.com/blogs
mydomains.com/blogs.html
```

This parameters should call the script:

```
mydomains.com/blogs/child-page.html
mydomains.com/blogs/another-page
mydomains.com/blogs.html/testin-page.html
mydomains.com/page.html
mydomains.com
```

I have attempted something like this, although it does not seem to work since `blogs.html` and `blogs` are still within the URL.

```
if(!document.URL.indexOf("blogs.html") >= 0 && !document.URL.indexOf("blogs") >= 0)
{ 
other script here
}
```

Is there any way that I can fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use js to do this?

Comment: If you are OK with using a plugin for this; there is a great one. You may want to check this out. [js-url](https://github.com/websanova/js-url)

Comment: @Daedalus - No, not at all. Open to PHP or other solutions. Just thought that maybe Javascript may have been the simplest solution.

Comment: @alix - Not really necessary since within my `if` statement, there will only be 1 tiny bit of code that will be blocking a div.

Comment: why look for what isn't and simply set server to identify that it is with a variable...or only include the script on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the pathname, then use the substring method to get everything after the last "/".

```
var pathName = window.location.pathname;
var pageName = pathName.substr( pathName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1 );

if( pageName != "blogs.html" && pageName != "blogs" ) {
    // do something.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!document.URL.endsWith("blogs.html"))
{ 
 // code here
}
```

string has endsWith() methods to accomplish this goal

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2FendsWith

or use a regular expression: $

```
if(!document.URL.search(/(blogs.html)$/) != -1) 
// return -1 means a string is not end with blogs.html
{ 
 // code here
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rchMe/